# Simple way to send a mail form command line from localhost

Tags: email, gmail, localhost

I want to send a simple E-mail notification (just an alert) from a bash script and came across `mail`, but there still you need to configure a mail server and I have not found any good tutorial on that. So is there another way to simply send an E-mail to my a gmail adress from the command-line using only my localhost?

Using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line

Comment: Yes but I am a bit worried about typing my password in a plain text file. Is there any security measure to ensure that it is somehow hashed or similar?

Comment: Personally I'm not sure but it seems like that thread has answers which don't involve saving your password to a text file.